# How to refresh a listview after clicking update button

Tags: c#, listview

I have a restock tab and inside that tab I have a `listview` that will display the products that has a quantity of 5 below so after clicking a row and after editing and clicking update, it's not being removed on my `listview` . Even though I've already edited the quantity.

here are the codes on my listview:

```
        SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
        DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

        MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");

        MySqlConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory where qt <= 5", MySqlConnection);

        //Clear the datatable to prevent duplicate generation of data in gridview.
        p_table.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter m_da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from inventory where qt <= 5", MySqlConnection);
        m_da.Fill(p_table);

        // Display items in the ListView control
        for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

            // Only row that have not been deleted
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                // Define the list items
                //(drow["bnum"].ToString());
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["pnum"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["pname"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["descr"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["dater"]).ToShortDateString());
                //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["exp"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["exp"]).ToShortDateString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["qt"].ToString());

                // Add the list items to the ListView
                listView4.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
}
```

here are the codes on my update button:

```
SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
        DataTable p_table = new DataTable();


        MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");
        MySqlConnection.Open();

        string pnum, pname, descr, qt, interval;
        //DateTime dater;

        pnum = pntext.Text;
        pname = nametext.Text;
        descr = desctext.Text;
        //dater = drtext.Value;
        //exp = detext.Text;
        qt = quantitytext.Text;
        interval = diff.Text;

        DateTime dater = drtext.Value.Date;
        DateTime exp = detext.Value.Date;

        SqlDataReader m_dr;


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Update [inventory] set pname = '" + pname + "',descr = '" + descr + "',dater = '" + dater + "',exp = '" + exp + "',qt = '" + qt + "',interval = '" + interval + "' where pnum = '" + pnum + "'", MySqlConnection);
        m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        m_dr.Close();
        listView4.SelectedItems.Clear();


        listView3.View = View.Details;
        command = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);
        m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (m_dr.Read())
        {

            //ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(m_dr["bnum"].ToString());


            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(m_dr["pnum"].ToString());


            lv.SubItems.Add(m_dr["pname"].ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(m_dr["descr"].ToString());
            //lv.SubItems.Add(m_dr["dater"].ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)m_dr["dater"]).ToShortDateString());
            //lv.SubItems.Add(m_dr["exp"].ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)m_dr["exp"]).ToShortDateString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(m_dr["qt"].ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(m_dr["interval"].ToString());
            listView3.Items.Add(lv);

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated!");
    }
```

Thank you.